# How to deal with the wallets with very small amount of Bitcoins?

Tags: wallet

The scenario is: You have a wallet with only 0.0001 BTC or less. The amount is less than the transaction fee. You want to transfer the coins to another wallet in order to reduce the wallet size. How can this be done?

Thank you good people:)

Comment: Do you really care how large the wallet.dat size gets?   It doesn't take much space at all.

Comment: @StephenGornick Some wallets can get really big, say over 200MB (with over 10,000 transactions). That makes it painful when backing up.

Comment: 10K is well above (by an order of magnitude or more) typical use.  And a 200 MB file size is a trivial transfer for today's computing environment.   

But yes, you can always send your funds to a new wallet and start from 0 transactions again.

Answer (score 4):

Two ways:

1. Create a transaction with no fee and wait as long as it takes for it to confirm.
2. Aggregate several such accounts into a single wallet so you can combine them in a single transaction.

Neither way is likely to be worth the effort though, unless you have a large number of such accounts.

Comment: Does the standard client still allow a transaction fee of 0?

Comment: If your transaction is over the size limit I don't believe it does.

Answer (score 2):

To spend the funds without paying a fee, you can transfer the private keys over to another client that doesn't impose a mandatory fee.  Like Blockchain.info/wallet.

But seriously ... 0.0001 is worth less than a penny.

Comment: Sometimes I view Bitcoins as a kind of gold, that thought adds more value to the pennies:)

Comment: Worth less than a penny now, maybe a small fortune in the future when you no longer have the wallet because you didn't think it was worth the trouble to keep it around.

Comment: Worth $6.02 as of 4/10/2021